# Facebook SDK for Unity: How to check if an invite has been sent?

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk, invite

I want to reward the player if he/she sends one or a specified number of invitations.
I assume for overall in between sessions you'd have to store it somewhere on the web. But for now I just wanna count the invites sent in the current session for simplicity's sake, so it doesn't have to be stored on the web.

Now naturally its easy to check if the user pressed a button that calls the FB.AppRequest() function, and count that, but he can easily press cancel without inviting anyone.

**So how can I know if an invite has been sent?** I can't find it in any of the reference or examples. And I'm pretty new to this and can't find ANY tutorials other than the official ones.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I came up with for my game. Keep in mind it only takes into account how many invites the user SENT, not how many of them were accepted...

I have a method that send the invite...

```
    void DoInviteAction()
    {
        FB.AppRequest(
                      message: "Can you beat my score in Sugar Hero?",
                      title: "Play Sugar Hero with me!",
                      callback: appRequestCallback
                      );
    }
```

And then, the corresponding callback. In my particular case, if the user invited 4 or more friends, he would get a free item...

```
private void appRequestCallback(FBResult result)
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            var responseObject = Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as Dictionary<string, object>;
            IEnumerable<object> objectArray = (IEnumerable<object>)responseObject["to"];

            if (objectArray.Count() >= 4)
            {
                // Give user a free item
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!